# Querying many to many relationship with LinqToSQL

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4.1, many-to-many

I have a database setup as follows (unfortunatelly was not allowed to publish diagram image in here so need to describe:
Responses table - contain RespondentID, QuestionID, ResponseOptionID
ResponseProperties - contain ResponsePropertyID, ResponsePropertyTypeID, Name
ResponsePropertyTypes - contain ResponsePropertyTypeID, Name

ResponsesInProperties (a many to many table) - contains ResponseID, ResponsePropertyID

There is a many to many relationship on ResponsesInProperties  table. This table does not show in EF of course.

Say I have two response property types "Country" and "Wave" and corresponding ResponeProperties "USA", "UK" and "Wave2011", "Wave2012".

Now I need to get back from the database all (and not duplicated) responses that would be in USA and also in Wave2012. The trick is that every response I need must be in both Wave2012 and USA. I am trying to achieve this with LINQ to SQL. The below is Linq I came up with that get's me the correct records but they appear many times for different properties. Limiting the properties gives me no records whatsoever....

Any help appreciated!

```
            var responses = from r in db.Responses
                            from rp in r.ResponseProperties
                            select new
                            {
                                RespondentID = r.RespondentID,
                                QuestionCode = r.Question.Code,
                                ResponseOptionCode = r.ResponseOption.Code,
                                ResponseOptionCodeName = r.ResponseOption.Text,
                                ResponsePropertyName = rp.Name,
                                ResponsePropertyTypeName = rp.ResponsePropertyType.Name
                            };
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, you are trying to do this with LINQ to SQL and not EF as they have rather different models for M-M. With LINQ to SQL, you do have to include the middle join table.

The key thing missing from your query at this point is the filter (Where) clauses. You need to specify them for both sides of the join to properly filter the results. You indicate that when you supply a filter you get back no records. Can you clarify your question with that filter as it may help to fix your underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your query cannot produce unique responses because you also get ResponsePropertyName and ResponsePropertyTypeName, which will duplicate the results.

This entity framework query -

```
from r in db.Responses
where r.ResponseProperties.Any (rp => rp.Name == "USA")
where r.ResponseProperties.Any (rp => rp.Name == "Wave2012")
select new
{
    RespondentID = r.RespondentID,
    QuestionCode = r.Question.Code,
    ResponseOptionCode = r.ResponseOption.Code,
    ResponseOptionCodeName = r.ResponseOption.Text,
};
```

does produce unique `Response`s that are in USA and in Wave2012. The produced sql will show two `EXISTS` predicates with `AND`.